# Вставка текста на сайт из буфера обмена

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, firefox, safari

Всем привет, столкнулась с такой проблемой реализовала функцию которая вызывается при клике на кнопку (вставить из буфера). В хроме, опера, яндекс, ie это работает одинаково всплывает плашка с разрешением вставить (ее 1 раз подтверждаешь и все больше не нужно подтверждать при будующей работе). В фаирфоксе вставка вообще не сработала, а в сафари каждый раз когда нажимаю кнопку всплывает нативная менюшка с 1 кнопкой вставить. Можно ли как-то сделать поведение в фаирфоксе и сафари одинаковым как и в хроме?

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: Возможно, можно поменять в настройках браузера что то, однако изменить поведение браузера кодом вы врят ли сможете.